# Require nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a Rails server with a RESTful API allows to create "communities" with "users".

To create a community I POST a JSON like this:

```
{
    "community": {
        "name": "community name"
    }
}
```

to */api/v1/communities*. The problem is that "name" must be mandatory, so if in CommunitiesController I do...

```
def community_params
    params.require(:community).permit(:name)
end
```

...and name is missing, I the user could create a community without name.

I'll like to force the presence of "name". I have tried to do

```
def community_params
    params.require(:community)
    params.require(community: [ :name ])
end
```

but I get

> ActionController::ParameterMissing in
>   Api::V1::CommunitiesController#create param is missing or the value is
>   empty: {:community=>[:name]}
>
> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"community"=>{"name"=>"community name"}}

How can I force the presence of a non-empty value of name?

Thanks in adance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb here and make assumption that you're working with a form submit and you don't want to add the record unless the name field is present.

To give the name field a "required" characteristic it should be declared in the model itself, community.rb, for instance:

```
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
```

In your controller I would suggest something like:

```
def community_params
      params.require(:community).permit(:name)
end
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You should use validation in your model instead of [strong params](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) feature:

```
validates_presence_of :name
```

strong params just check hierarchy of your params and protect from mass-assigment.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats what I wanted :)